# Java String.contains vs String.contentEquals

Tags: java

What is the real difference between these two methods?
Both have the same signature and return `true` if the string contains the `CharSequence` given as a parameter and `false` if it doesn’t.

Methods:

```
boolean contains(CharSequence string)

boolean contentEquals(CharSequence string)
```

Comment: Consider "abcde". That *contains* "bcd", but it doesn't have *equal content* to "bcd". Where did you see "contains" in the description of `contentEquals`? (Perhaps you're looking at old docs?)

Comment: @JonSkeet could be, i saw the description of these two methods in Herbert Schildt book fifth release 2015 y. Could it be deprecated?

Comment: And im not at the PC to verify the actual java docs

Comment: I think it's more likely that it just isn't a terribly good description. Looking at the Javadocs is likely to be a better plan. (As a side-note, I'd consider that as part of the research to do before asking a question. You may not be able to do it right away, but I would assume there isn't *that* much urgency in asking the question. If you want to avoid forgetting to check and ask, I'd suggest emailing yourself as a reminder.)

Comment: Just to clarify (based on the 9th edition, not the 5th): `contentEquals: Returns true if the invoking string contains the same 
string as str. Otherwise, returns false.` compared with `contains: Returns true if the invoking object contains the 
string specified by str. Returns false otherwise. ` Are you sure that you not just ignored the word `same`?

Comment: Hey @sn42 thanks for clarifications, your description is correct, my book has another translation and has a typo missing “same” word, i’d double checked. A mister above is right i should make some research at home before posting this, but anyway very thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `contentEquals()` the parameter has to be exactly equals to the string; with `contains()` instead is sufficient that the parameter is inside the string, the string can cointain also other characters.

```
String foo = "foo";
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("foofoo");
StringBuffer str2 = new StringBuffer("foo");
foo.contains(str); // false
str.contains(foo); // true
foo.contentEquals(str) // false
foo.contentEquals(str2) // true
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, Your answer is correct but... looking at Herbert Schildt at 17th chapter were these methods have identical description.

Comment: They have same signature, but they do completely different jobs.

Comment: The example I provide explain how they differ. contentEquals() will give the same output of contains() only if the 2 strings are exactly equals. It's a subcase of cointains().

Comment: Yeah we both know that...well i guess the book has a typo, you can check it too if you wish. Herbert Schildt fifth release 16.2 a list of String methods page 488